# Closure and holding posts off-topic

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, closed-questions, on-hold

With questions like [this one](https://health.stackexchange.com/q/11240/7951) there is the facility to flag to close as off-topic but with this type of question (requests for information on suicide without pain) there is no question in this vein which can be on-topic.  When closed or held, readers are still able to comment which can be as damaging if the wrong advice iss given.

Should there be a facility for flagging to delete?  This way no damaging responses can be given at all.

Comment: Users with 2000 rep can vote to delete questions on that site. Usually 3 votes will delete it. Moderators can delete it with a single vote.